# Problem with resizing columns added dynamically in run time to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a simple form with RightToLeft = true.
in the form there is a panel with AutoScroll = true. and in the panel there is a DataGridView with a very long width (2000px).
user can add columns by clicking "Add Column" Button.

[image]

this is code of "Add column" button click event:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _index++;
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() { Name = $"Col{_index}",HeaderText = $"Col{_index}"});

    }
```

the problem is: when user add some columns and clicks on one of ColumnHeader's border for first time to drag it and resize the column the panel will be scrolled to end left and column will be very wide that is not naturally my desired behavior. in the next clicks and resizing every thing works perfect.
how can i resolve this problem?
thanks

Comment: Do you have `[DataGridView].AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill`, maybe? Otherwise, you can set the Column's `Width` when you create one.

Comment: AutoSizeColumnsMode has its default value = none.Setting Width when creating the column does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the columns each time you add a new one

you can check this

**PS : Make sure to set Row Header to false so there will be no conflict with the grid width**

```
private void updateWidth()
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn item in dataGrid.Columns)
            {
                item.Width = dataGrid.Columns.Count == 0 ?
                                dataGrid.Width
                                : (int)(dataGrid.Width / dataGrid.Columns.Count);
            }
        }
int _index = 0;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){

            var col = new DataGridViewColumn();
            col.Name = $"Col{_index++}";
            col.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
            updateWidth();
        }
    }
```

**For a fixed width you can do ( with AutoSizeColumnsMode set to None):**

```
int _index = 0;
int fixedWidth = 200;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

            var col = new DataGridViewColumn();
            col.Name = $"Col{_index++}";
            col.Width = fixedWidth;
            col.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            dataGrid.Columns.Add(col);
 }
```